# Selenium File download validation works locally but fails on Jenkins with null pointer exception

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver

I have an application that downloads the file into the Downloads section of our local computer which generally is the case in all the operating systems. I want to validate this in Selenium. Below is the piece of code I am using.

```
public boolean validateDownloadedFile(String fileType) {
        boolean downloadedFile = false;
        WaitActions.wait(Utils.LONG_WAIT_DEFAULT_MILLS);
        if (!System.getProperty("browser").contains("local")) {
            ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());
        }
        File downloadLocation = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "downloads");
        File[] totalFiles = downloadLocation.listFiles();

        for (File file : totalFiles) {

            switch (fileType) {
            case ("single"):
            case ("selected"):
                if (file.getName().contains("docx")) {
                    downloadedFile = true;
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case ("all"):
                if (file.getName().contains("_all_attachments.zip")) {
                    downloadedFile = true;
                    break;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        return downloadedFile;
    }
```

But this code fails in Jenkins at the start of for each loop itself with a null pointer exception. That means the file is not downloaded in that location it seems. Locally when I run this, the test case is passed. Is there any way I can validate this in Jenkins properly?